# If you replace prototype.constructor for security reasons, is there a way to recover it?

Tags: javascript, security

I want to replace Date.prototype.constructor and the global window.Date (while keeping a reference to the original in the closure that replaces it). Is there any way to recover the original in a hosted V8 (not the browser)? As I understand it captured closure variables are truly private in JavaScript and can't be accessed. AFAIK those were the only two references to the Date constructor, so once I replace them, it's inaccessible. Is that true?

Full question and code here: [Replace builtin Date without being able to recover original constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625568/replace-builtin-date-without-being-able-to-recover-original-constructor)

I'm re-asking this with a different wording because I think the original question obfuscates what I'm really asking about, and perhaps that's why it didn't get much attention. Apologies if that's against the rules here.

Comment: "*Is there any way to recover the original?*" [Create a reset of javascript Array prototype when Array.prototype has been modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13990187)

Comment: *captured closure variables are truly private in JavaScript and can't be accessed* Not entirely, if you can run code earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424277

Comment: I suspect your approach might be fundamentally flawed here. If you're running your code in the client, there is no actual protection against tampering. Your code might be modified before it even executes. Or blocked entirely. Moreover, by yourself tampering with native objects, you might break any other scripts on the page that aren't "evil". What are you even trying to protect against that involves trying to control the environment?

Comment: @VLAZ I'm running a carefully controlled environment on the server in V8, see the linked question for more details. I edited my question to clarify that. So that shouldn't matter - if I don't let client code execute before mine.